# Latest versions of spring-boot-starter-parent won't run tests with maven command

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I was testing a small example of spring-boot and I realized if I use `mvn test` command with spring-boot-starter-parent version `2.7.0` it will not find any tests.
But if I use an older version like `2.3.12.RELEASE` maven will detect all tests.

here is the pom file: almost original from initializr

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rectangle-api</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have two test classes, one mvc test and another regular test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoServiceTest {
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class DemoControllerTest {
```

These two classes will run with `mvn test` AND find the `JUnit` dependencies if I downgrade my pom parent to `2.3.12.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to spring-boot 2.4.0 [release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes) JUnit 5 vintage was removed from `spring-boot-starter-test` thus Junit 4 dependencies like `org.junit.Test` are not automatically available anymore, unless manually imported as maven/gradle dependency.

Using Junit 5 dependencies like `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` "fixed" the project.